# Using JPA domain classes in Grails

Tags: java, grails, jpa, groovy, grails-orm

I want to use a JPA domain model in an application developed using the latest Grails milestone (2.0.0.M1). The JPA domain classes are in the `src\java` directory of the application.

Based on [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernatejpa-domain-model-with-grails/) which describes how to use an existing JPA domain model in a Grails app, I created `grails-app/conf/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml` with a list of my JPA-annotated classes.

In case anyone is bored enough to want to run the app themselves, it's available [here](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/jpa-bug.zip). When you run the application the following error occurs on startup

```
Error 2011-08-04 23:28:19,777 [Thread-8] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creati
ng bean with name 'grailsDomainClassMappingContext': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.domain.GrailsDomainCla
ssMappingContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.domain.GrailsDomainCl
assMappingContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 123 | addPersistentEntityInternal in org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   115 | addPersistentEntity in     ''
|   127 | addPersistentEntityInternal in     ''
|   115 | addPersistentEntity in     ''
|   127 | addPersistentEntityInternal in     ''
|   115 | addPersistentEntity in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Curiously, the problem only seems to be triggered by domain classes that have relationships with other domain classes. If you remove all domain classes except `SystemProperty` (which doesn't refer to other domain classes), the app starts without error.

Comment: Why do not you Create the JAR file of your domainl model and refernce that in Grails App.

Comment: Is the .war file in that ZIP distribution up-to-date? I don't see those dependencies in there. I also don't find the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: There is no .war file in the ZIP, just the source code of the app. You can generate a war by running `grails war` from the application root, or run it (without generating a .war first) with `grails run-app`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `META-INF/persistence.xml` ([example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging)) (I don't know where exactly to place it, but it should ultimately go to `WEB-INF/META-INF/persistence.xml`, and include your jar file there (in `<jar-file>` element). Then of course you will need all respective spring beans (`LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` for example)

Comment: I think I already have the spring beans I need in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml`. Can you show an example of what the content of the `persistence.xml` should look like?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging

Comment: Are you sure about the path `WEB-INF/META-INF/persistence.xml`, did you mean either `WEB-INF/persistence.xml` or `META-INF/persistence.xml`?

Comment: WEB-INF/classes/META-INF, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[The 1.3.7 documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html#15.1%20Using%20Hibernate%20XML%20Mapping%20Files) says

> Simply place the mapping files into grails-app/conf/hibernate and
>   either put the Java files in src/java or (if the domain model is
>   stored in a JAR) the packaged classes into the project's lib
>   directory.

I didn't see your jar in the `lib` directory in your source code. Could this be it?

Comment: I didn't see anything in the documentation that says you can have the java jar in anything but the lib directory so maybe it isn't possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the grails startup scripts ( $GRAILS_HOME$/bin/grails and $GRAILS_HOME$/bin/startGrails), you can find out the classpath argument being sent to the grails application launcher org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.

When you execute the command grails generate-all com.model.User, the grails expects it to be available in the source folder or the lib directory. In your scenario, the jar is available as part of Maven dependency. This information is not passed along the grails startup script. You need to specify this information.

The startup script has the option to specify the classpath. Hence, you need to invoke the grails command with the classpath option that specifies the location of the jars.

grails generate-all -cp E:\workspace\AppDomain.jar

You need to mention the jar with other commands as well. 
Ex: grails run-app -cp E:\workspace\AppDomain.jar

You will need a mechanism to get all Maven dependencies as classpath argument.

I have tested with a sample JPA domain class and this works.